# Jenkins on Docker for Android gives No server to serve request

Tags: android, docker, jenkins

Using mac for 
Very simple Android project need CI for which Jenkins installed on Docker using jenkinsci/blueocean image.

Android studio 3.0.1 runs Android project perfectly, whereas on running Jenkins job for project gives "NO Server to serve request for app:mergeDebugResources" task

Need help in understanding why this problem occur in jenkins and not in Android studio whereas both docker containing jenkins and android studio both running on same machine i.e. Mac.

> - What went wrong: 
>     Caused by: Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>     No server to serve request. Check logs for details.   at
>     com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.postWriteAction(MergedResourceWriter.java:622)
>     at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:46)
>     at
>     com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:238)
>     at
>     com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:301)
>     at
>     com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:412)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:258)
>     ... 39 more     Suppressed: java.lang.RuntimeException: No slave process
>     to process jobs, aborting         at
>     com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.shutdown(WorkQueue.java:168)      at
>     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.QueuedResourceProcessor.end(QueuedResourceProcessor.java:147)
>       at
>     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.close(QueueableAapt2.java:117)
>       at
>     com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:266)
>       at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)      at
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)         at
>     org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)